# Как убрать полосу над функцией в phpstorm

Tags: phpstorm, php

Как убрать полосу над функцией в `phpstorm`

[image: img].

Comment: Я не вижу подчеркивания функции на вашем скриншоте. Вы имеете в виду полосу НАД функцией?

Comment: да) именно ее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
File->Settings->IDE Settings->Editor->Appearance->Show method separators
```

Comment: щас попробую

Comment: Спасибо то что нужно!

Answer (score 1):

```
File–>Settings–>Project Settings–>Inspections снимаем галочку Spelling.
```

Comment: Спасибо, после перезапуска заработало!

Comment: а нет мне показалось, не помогло

Answer (score 0):

там ещё горизонтальная полоска сверху остается, её можно убрать

> File->Settings->Editor->Color&Fonts->General->Method separator color